# How Cashew and Mobile Roadie work (online iPhone app creation tools)?

Tags: iphone

I discovered today two websites that allow people creating **native** iPhone apps directly in the browser!
theses are the links:

- http://mobileroadie.com/
- http://cashew.madebykawet.com/

I tried the second one and it's really amazing:
You create your app online then customize it by adding RSS feeds, tabs, videos, etc ... and to test, all you have to do is to download the "cashew" app, enter your nickname and password and then preview your app. Amazing.

How did they do it? How the whole system works? It's pretty weird because you create an app that will not be submitted to the appstore and will be published live!!

Thank you,

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting things :-) Without any deeper insights to both applications, I think the main point is that there is an app connecting to a protected section of a CMS. Content, navigation, media, etc. is stored in this CMS database and is loaded after starting the app either from server, if you are online, or from cache. All GUI elements like views, tabs, ... are created programmatically using the information from CMS.

There seem to be only few differences between both approaches.

- 1) mobileroadies.com

You create your own app once which will then be submitted by the mobileroadie guys. The FAQ writes "Once you’re ready, let us know through the CMS. We check your App and assuming there are no issues submit it to Apple and/or Google on your behalf". That means you cannot test your app on the device until you have got the approval.

If once accepted by Apple, content will be updated by connecting to their web site when the user starts the app. Videos, music and so on are provided as streams and seem to be available only within the app, as long as they are not hosted on youtube or any other location outside mobileroadie's CMS database.

- 2) cashew

There is one app for all developers to test their stuff on the device, because on start you have to provide your user name and password. This is different from the simulator only approach from mobileroadies (and fancy :-). The technical process of creating an app seems pretty similar i.e. CMS with database and dynamic creation of views. If you are satisfied with your app, again they will do the approval process for you: "For 590€ (then 29€/month) we add it on the App Store"

There are some small differences in pricing model. If you are planning to work with such a system, you should take a closer look at testing and versioning capabilities. For me as developer it's extremely important to test new content before going live.

Hope that helps and: My thoughts are pure guessing I am not connected at all to one of the companies.

Regards

Kay

Comment: That what I exactly what I thought. I think that the most interesting model is the cashew's. Especially for the dev process.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :-) Maybe I will take a closer look at cashew one day, if customers like to have some quick and cheap apps. I think this is a pretty good busines case - although not so interesting for the developer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://appmakr.com

it's basically free if you have your own apple dev account.

the html tab offers a lot of power

Answer (score 0):

I used [snappii.com](http://www.snappii.com) for my apps. I can test apps on my iphone without problems.