# softwares to make apps for iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any other software that can make application for iphone other than xcode...

Please also check th [link](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/) and tell is it only for android or can i make iphone applications using it?
Because it just make and run it on device and iphone need adhoc...
please reply...
thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is It Possible to Create an iPhone App without Apple Products?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533156/is-it-possible-to-create-an-iphone-app-without-apple-products)

Comment: See also [Is there a multiplatform framework for developing iPhone / Android applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953/is-there-a-multiplatform-framework-for-developing-iphone-android-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other software that can make application for iphone other than xcode...

Yes, there are several frameworks that can make applications for iPhone. [Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/) allows you to use Flash applications on your iPhone. [UDK](http://www.udk.com/news-beta-dec2010) can do it, as can [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/unity/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Titanium appcelerator for building iPhone and android applications. You will still have to install iPhone SDK and Android SDK. Titamiun appcelerator uses java script for developing application for iPhone and Android

Check this [link](http://www.appcelerator.com/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This software is only for android development. Try this [software](http://www.airplaysdk.com) for iPhone app development.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question is interesting for you:

[How Cashew and Mobile Roadie work (online iPhone app creation tools)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271539/how-cashew-and-mobile-roadie-work-online-iphone-app-creation-tools/4312412#4312412)